# Obtain the scheduled publish date/time for a previously uploaded and scheduled youtube video

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am traversing the uploads playlist using the youtube v3 api, and fetching details for each video using videos/list({id}). I'm requesting the snippet and contentDetails parts, but I'm finding that snippet.publishedAt and contentDetails.videoPublishedAt fields always reflect the uploaded date, not the scheduled date (for videos that were scheduled when uploaded).

I have requested all of the documented parts and don't see a 'scheduledDate' field anywhere; wondering if there is another technique to obtain this info?

Comment: if the answer solved your problem, please consider [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs, you have at your disposal the following property:

> [`status.publishAt`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#status.publishAt) (datetime)
>
> The date and time when the video is scheduled to publish. It can be set only if the privacy status of the video is private. The value is specified in [ISO 8601](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) format. Note the following two additional points about this property's behavior:
>
> - If you set this property's value when calling the [videos.update](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update) method, you must also set the [status.privacyStatus](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#status.privacyStatus) property value to `private` even if the video is already private.
> - If your request schedules a video to be published at some time in the past, the video will be published right away. As such, the effect of setting the `status.publishAt` property to a past date and time is the same as of changing the video's [privacyStatus](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#status.privacyStatus) from `private` to `public`.

For to obtain this property from the [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) API endpoint, do not forget to pass to the parameter [`part`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#part) the value `status` too.